# Why does Chrome have so many 'Not Responding ' processes on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, battery

[image: Activity Monitor]

I'm running OS X Yosemite Developer Preview and I noticed that ever since I switched to Google Chrome from Safari, the battery of my MacBook Pro with Retina Display 15-inch (early 2013) has reduced significantly.

So, I opened up Activity Monitor to investigate resource usage and say many of these processes of Google Chrome come up as 'Not Responding'.

Why does this happen ? Is this draining my battery ? Because I used to get 6-7 hours of battery life and now I get 3-4.

Comment: me too having the same question.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Chrome for each plug-in, process, application, or there is a separate tab process. These processes can be seen and forced to complete the task manager Chrome.
Open Activity Monitor и Task Manager, look at the processes "Google Chrome Helper", identify them by PID.
In the "monitor activity" Chrome Helper shown as "not responding", but in the manager is operating normally. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5572267?start=15&tstart=0